# What does "hammer that home" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "They continuously infused that at home"?

> People ask me – I’m in music, he’s in business – is he disappointed? I tell them we do the same thing, what we love. And that’s what he infused as we grew up, and my mother did as well. Find something you love, that’s the key. And they really **hammered that home**, and in so many different ways. So it couldn’t have been easier, really, to be his son.

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/jimclash/2017/04/18/peter-buffett-warrens-youngest-son-says-growing-up-buffett-was-nothing-fancy/2/#385e01ff39c5

Comment: A quick search online will give you detailed explanations and examples of the expression. You might start with: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hammer+home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, it means "to make somebody truly understand or internalise something" – in this case, their "motto" of following that which you like.

Answer (score 0):

"hammered that home" can have two different meanings.

First there is the expression that the nail that sticks up is the one that gets hammered. So if the nail is pounded in, then it conforms with the norm and doesn't stick out.

> So "My parents caught me sneaking in late and hammered home that I must be on time in the future." -- In other words my parents made a strong point that I should not ignore the curfew time.

The second meaning would be like at a ball game.

> "Joe really hammered that home." -- In other words Joe kicked the soccer ball very hard into the net. So the ball got a strong whack, not a tap.